# How to identify new files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Just wondering if there is a way to identify new files that are added to a path in HDFS? For example, if already some files were present for sometime. Now I have added new files today. So wanted to process only those new files. What is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Further info: There is going to be only one folder which receives files i.e. sub-folders cannot be created under the main one on  a daily basis. Only file level information has to be used to understand whether the file is processed or not

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a java code to do this. These steps may help:

```
1. Before adding new files, fetch the last modified time (hadoop fs -ls /your-path). Lets say it as mTime.
2. Next upload new files into hdfs path
3. Now filter the files that are greater than mTime. These files are to be processed. Make your program to process only these files.
```

This is just a hint for developing your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is Mapreduce then you can create output directory appended with timestamp on daily basis.

Like

```
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(hdfsFilePath
            + timestamp_start); // start at 12 midnight for example:  1427241600 (GMT) --you can write logic to get epoch time
```